# Highcharts Error #13 : Rendering div not found

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, highcharts, meteor-blaze

I'm working with Javascript (Meteor) and trying to implement a Highchart with drilldown. After thoroughly testing the logic part for correctness, I've verified that the data passed onto my Highchart is correct. However, I am getting Error #13 because there seems to be a problem with how I am setting the "renderTo:" field within the "chart:" options in the chart, which currently looks like this:

```
return chart = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            type: 'bar'
        },
//other fields
```

In the HTML file, I use this template and invoke it in the body:

```
<template name= "myTemplate">
  {{> highchartsHelper chartId="chart" chartWidth="100%" charHeight="100%" chartObject=topGenresChart}}
</template>

<body>
   //other stuff
   {{> myTemplate}}
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure `renderTo` is necessary when using `{{> highchartshelper }}`? Try leaving out that option.

Comment: Have you tried to use the solution described on our official website: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/195-meteor-standalone ?